# Css positioning on form div not working correctly

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to position a div in my form named label beside the input form that I have it works for the first select box in my form. However it doesn't seem to be positioned the same for the subsequent input boxes or select boxes instead it seems to centre the label div.

In addition the div called context is meant to appear to the right of the input box/select box but is not been positioned there correctly. I have used the style of formatting forms and it has worked perfectly in the past however is not working out as good here.

Important Point.... you will need to reize the html screen in jsfiddle to see the problem that I have.

**[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgvLk/)**

Does anybody have a solution to this problem.
Any help will be welcomed!

insert.php

```
  <div id="contactform"> <!-- Contact Form Div -->
    <div id="formWrap">
    <div id="form">
    <form action="insert.php" method="post" name="insert" id="comments_form">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">No. of Bedroms</div>
    <div class="input"> 
            <select name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms" class="detail">

                </div> <!-- end input -->
                 <div class="context"> e.g. John Smith </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->
            </select> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Description</div>
    <div class="input">            
            <textarea name="description" name="description" id="description" class="detail"></textarea>
                 </div> <!-- end input -->
                 <div class="context"> e.g. 3 Bedroom house in London close to University bus stops. </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->      
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Road Name</div>
    <div class="input">        
            <input type="input" name="roadname" id="roadname" class="detail"/>
                 </div> <!-- end input -->
                 <div class="context"> e.g. New Road </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->                      
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Message" />
                    <div class="subimt"> </div> <!-- end submit -->                
        </form>
 </div> <!-- end form -->
 </div> <!-- end form wrapper -->​
```

style.css

```
/*    ---------------------------------------------------------------------    * 
 *    Contact Form Styling 
 *    ---------------------------------------------------------------------    */

#formWrap {
background-color:#232527;
width:85%;
margin:0px 0px 0px 100px;
color:#FFF;    
padding: 16px 10px 40px;
}

#formWrap #form {
border-top:1px solid #EEE;
width:100%;

}

#form .row {
border-bottom:1px solid dotted #EEE;
display:block;
line-height: 38px;
overflow:auto;
padding: 24px 0px;
width: 100%;
}

#form .row .label {
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width:180px;
text-align:right;
float:left;
padding-right:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}

#form .row .input {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
/*width:auto;*/
width:285px;
}

#form .row .input2 {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
/*width:auto;*/
width:466px;
}

#form .row .context {
color:#FFF;
font-size:11px;
font-style:italic;
line-height:14px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width:200px;
float:left;
}

.detail {
width:260px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
padding:7px 8px;
margin:0px;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#E9E9E9;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.detail:focus {
background:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;    
}

.mess:focus {
background:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;    
}    

.mess {
width:450px;
max-width:450px;
height:280px;    
overflow:auto;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
padding:7px 8px;
line-height: 1em;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#E9E9E9;
border:1px solid #CCC;

}

#form #submit{ 
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin-top:-10px;
margin-left:200px;
cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffffff; 
color: #232527;
border-radius: 24px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px 32px;
-webkit-transition: background .1s linear;
-moz-transition: background .1s linear;
-o-transition: background .1s linear;
-ms-transition: background .1s linear;
transition: background .1s linear;
text-decoration: none;
border:none;    
}

#form #submit:hover{
    color:#5eb9f9;

}


span.error {
display:block;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-image:url(../images/x.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-postion:left 6px;
padding-left:25px;
font-size:11px;
}

#formWrap h2 {
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text=shadow: 1px 1px 1px #CCC;
color:#FFF;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
margin-left:25px;    
}
```

​

Comment: All the rest of the 'rows' are nested inside the first row. Is this intentional?

Comment: This example is huge, finding the problem is a needle in a haystack situation. Simplify your example down to the smallest representative peice. Just in simplifying you might discover the problem on your own.

Comment: "Please make your question complete by including relevant, formatted code inline (don't just link to jsfiddle.net)."

Comment: The fact that the system didn't let you post the question with just the jsFiddle link, doesn't mean you get to "Oh, let's put it in code block, great now it works!" It means you should add some code to your question. ALSO, Please make a **simplified** test-case of your problem. Don't throw this massive block of code at us.

Comment: Another reason to add some real code is that links in code blocks are not clickable.

Comment: i have edited the post to include a simplified version of the code in addition I have reflected this update on the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mgvLk/1/ sorry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing `</select>` tag comes to late. If it's moved to directly after the opening `<select ...>` (and thus no longer contains `div` tags), it seems to work.

Comment: I'd recommend trying a [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) for future problems. This solution could easily have been found using one. Proper indentation also helps.